# Will inline function avoid external condition?

Tags: c++, optimization, inline

I want to confirm if a certain kind optimization that came to my mind is possible.

```
// test.h
class Test
{
public:
    static void Main();

private:
    __forceinline static bool func1()
    {
        return ((externalCond1 && externalCond2) ? true : false);
    }
}

// test.cpp
#include "test.h"

void Test::Main()
{  
    if(func1() == true)
    {  
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Would the condition at `Main` be optimized away thanks to the inlined `func1`, and prevent it from actually being tested? (resulting in only testing the conditions within `func1`).

This is only an example code. But, since my real inlined function is about that short anyways, I would simply copy the conditions within `func1` to all places that wanted to call this function, if it turns out that this optimization is impossible.

Finally, I would like to know (only if the optimization is possible) whether it would simply be a case of the "Return Value Optimization" paradigm.

Comment: A C++ compiler is permitted, but not required, to employ any optimization that has no observable effects. Your desired optimization has no observable effects. Your C++ compiler may or may not implement this optimization, at its discretion. It is allowed to do that, but is not required to do so. Typically, whether or not this optimization takes place depends on specific compilation options you choose when you compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

If the `__forceinline` attribute is honored, your code is equivalent to

```
void Test::Main()
{  
    if (((externalCond1 && externalCond2) ? true : false) == true)
    {  
        //Do something
    }
}
```

If your conditions are external in the sense of being variables external to this compilation unit, then they cannot be optimized away as their values are unknown at compile-time.